# JAXBException on creating JAXB Context

Tags: java, jaxb, applet, java-web-start

When I run application as standalone Java program, it works well. When I run it as an applet, it throws JAXBException with following stacktrace.

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: jaxb.properties in package com/test/package does not contain the javax.xml.bind.context.factory property.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

When I add a jaxb.properties, i get the below error -

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory.createContext([Ljava.lang.Class;, java.util.Map)]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I added following jars to classpath -

- jaxws-rt-2.2.1
- jsr311-api-1.1.1
- jersey-core-1.2
- jersey-client-1.2

What causes this error. Am I missing any dependencies.

Edit:
I am using Java 7 u 59 on both browser and development environment.

Comment: Looks like you libs are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey version 1.2 seems outdated. I think Jersey 2.21 is the current version. Furthermore, you should inspect which JDK/JRE you are using to run your program. Does the applet run in the same environment/Java version as when you start it as an application?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check are you using the same JRE. You can do that [here.](http://javatester.org/version.html) And as @LarsGendner mentioned - [download](https://jaxb.java.net/) JAXB 2.2.* jar, because 1.2 is outdated.

Second: Check out this topic: [How can I use JAXB from an unsigned applet (without signing it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084391/how-can-i-use-jaxb-from-an-unsigned-applet-without-signing-it)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information provided, here are my inputs. Please note anything which require your input/you-to-try-out, I have marked it as `<try-out>`.

Firstly `<try-out>` following:

a. Verify you don't see multiple java versions as **checked** inside: widnows-> control panel->java->java tab->view java locations. Basically this is to ensure your java application and applet using same JRE.

**Regarding your first exception :** `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: jaxb.properties in package com/test/package does not contain the javax.xml.bind.context.factory property`

This is problem of JRE not able to locate an JAXB implementation. Please go through the [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) and locate section "Discovery of JAXB implementation".
It mentions that following 4 locations are used to identify JAXB implementation:

1. Finding jaxb.properties at package level directory
2. System property JAXB_CONTEXT_FACTORY
3. Looking for /META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext file in all jars
4. Default JVM specific implementation.

Now you are getting this exception **only in case of Applet NOT for JAVA application.** You mentioned that both java application and applet are using same JDK + additional jars. Only reason I can think of difference between applet and application environment could be due to **point 2** above.

`<try-out>` following:

b.Can you check if you are specifying JAXB_CONTEXT_FACTORY as system property when you run java application (perhaps through eclipse or something)

c. May be you can print all system properties in your code:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.list(System.out);
```

and verify if JAXB context factory is set there or not?

**Regarding your second exception :**
after you added jaxb.properties file, you received your second exception. It could be due to following reason:-
exception stack trace shows you might have specified `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory` in `JAXB.properties` file.
Now if you see again [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) and locate first SPEC REQUIREMENT for JAXBContext provider: the provider must supply an implementation class containing the following method signatures:

```
public static JAXBContext createContext( Class[] classes, Map<String,Object> properties ) throws JAXBException
```

Further Now if you google content of `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory` class, you can see at this [site](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/developer/JAXBContextFactory.java) that this class does NOT contain the method `createConext()`; it only define a method call `createJAXBContext(`). Please note this class is internally called by `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext` which extension of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` class.

`<try-out>` following:

d. you should specify a proper value of `javax.xml.bind.context.factory` in `jaxb.properties` file which point to a class implementing `createConext()` operation.

**Finally, last point :**
There is possiblity that you are specifying correct factory in `jaxb.properties` but its value might not be picked by runtime and instead runtime is picking JAXB implementation value from other mechanisms specified in points 1-4 above.  This can be case of multiple JAXB factory implementations present in JVM runtime.

`<try-out>` following:

e. In such situations, best to use Java endorsed override mechanism as specified in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215409/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-version-of-the-jaxb-implementation-in-java-jre-1-6)

Comment: @ACN: could you please let me know did you try out the options I had provided-what worked for you? This would help others too perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception i came to know that your WS is referring to the java rt.jar and not referring to the jar added by you in the classpath.

So from this i can conclude the jar is not placed exactly in the classPath.

Answer (score 0):

Second Exception:
Check the class getting referred from which jar and replace the proper jar file which has createjaxbcontext method.

Use the proper version of jar in the classpath(jaxws-rt).