# JAXB with Java Applets (java 7 - with all permissions)

Tags: java, jaxb, applet, java-web-start

If i create JAXBContext `(JAXBContext.newInstance(Abc.class))` and run this class file in my system, it works fine. But the same code throws error, when I run it as an applet, with the same JRE (and same PC). First error I get is -

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: jaxb.properties in package com/test/package does not contain the javax.xml.bind.context.factory property.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

If I add a jaxb.properties in the package com/test/package, I get another error. This time it is -

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory.createContext([Ljava.lang.Class;, java.util.Map)]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

jaxb.properties contents -

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory
```

I have tried changing java version too.
What might be possible cause of this error.

Comment: Are you *sure* you are running the same JRE? Check which JRE your browser is using here: http://javatester.org/version.html

Comment: You tagged your question both `applet` and `java-web-start`, but those are not the same. Which is it?

Comment: @Andreas it is a java applet, and java version i tested is same.

Comment: Which Java version is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use JAXB from an unsigned applet (without signing it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084391/how-can-i-use-jaxb-from-an-unsigned-applet-without-signing-it)

Comment: @Andreas *"You tagged your question both applet and java-web-start, but those are not the same. Which is it?"*  No, they are not the same, but JWS can **deploy** applets.  JWS has been able to do that since it was first introduced.  OP - Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: I have explained answer to your question in this [post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268883/jaxbexception-on-creating-jaxb-context/32334379